# What is the regex for positive number range 18-65? It must accept only two digits

Tags: javascript, regex, vue.js

I wanted a regex for range between 18-65.

I used this -> `1[89]|[2-5][0-9]|6[0-5]` but it is not working properly, and also accepting more than two digits. Please suggest.

I wanted to take input of age ranging between 18-65.

Comment: regex is overkill for this. `num >= 18 && num <=65` is enough

Comment: `regex` is **not** the right tool for this job. It can be used to check if a string looks like a number (i.e. contains only digits) but this is where its power ends. Then parse the string, get a number and compare the number with the limits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are quite close, the issue with your expression is that you are missing anchor tags, which say that the regex engine should match only the given string (and make it fail if anything else comes before or after).

Changing your expressions slightly, to this : `^(1[89]|[2-5][0-9]|6[0-5])$` (example [here](https://regex101.com/r/t0YGVo/1)). The `^` in front ensures that the matching starts at the very beginning of the string, while the `$` at the end ensures that matching stops at the end of the string. This ensures you that the string provided matches the pattern you want, *as a whole*, thus, `19` would be matched, but `119` would not.

Alternatively (as it will most likely be proposed), it will be easier to split by `-` and then use the usual mathematical operators.

Comment: @RoshanYadav: If the answer helped you, please mark it for others

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do that with regex you have to use `^` and `$`. In this way the number (between 18 and 65) would be the only accepted input (no other characters):

```
^(1[89]|[2-5][0-9]|6[0-5])$
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```js
const regex = /^(1[8-9])|([2-5][0-9])|(6[0-5])$/

console.log(regex.test(17)) // false
console.log(regex.test(18)) // true
console.log(regex.test(65)) // true
console.log(regex.test(66)) // false
```

But, as already stated in comments, regex is an overkill for doing this.

You should use regex to extract numeric values and then use a different function to compare the extracted value to the needed value.

Comment: This is working but accepting more than two digits.

Answer (score 0):

Though as per AZ_ comment mentioning condition is good in case you want to use regex then try following.

```
^1[8-9]$|^[2-5][0-9]$|^6[0-5]$
```

Comment: Also passes for 11-17

Comment: Fails for 20, 30, 40, 50

Comment: @CinCout, Thanks for letting me know, changed it now.

Comment: This matches `1800000`

Answer (score 0):

Lots of answers....maybe check this handy website in case you need other ranges in future? http://gamon.webfactional.com/regexnumericrangegenerator/

```
\b(1[89]|[2-5][0-9]|6[0-5])\b
```

Comment: This matches `abc*$^189245%/:`

Comment: Edited example to match whole word.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(^1[8-9]$)|(^[2-5][0-9]$)|(^6[0-5]$)
```

[Here is Demo](https://regex101.com/r/abLweH/3)